# Find Images in the Website Which are used Never

Tags: asp.net, html, performance, image, optimization

How can I detect image that is never used in the website, to improve loading speed of the whole content?.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: How would removing an image that is never used improve loading speeds?

Comment: If an image is never used—that is, is never referenced in the HTML—then it won't be downloaded to the browser when somebody views it. Removing such images won't speed things up.

Comment: so, they are not loaded?.. hmm... I didn't know... just answer I''l accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an image is never used or referenced in the html then it won't be downloaded by the browser.

Even if they are out on your hosting, they will just be sitting there like storage, and not have an effect on speed of page times.

Here is a good reference for loading time optimization.

http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/site-speed-performance/

1. Defer Loading Content When Possible
2. Use External JS and CSS Files
3. Use Caching Systems
4. Avoid Resizing Images in HTML
5. Stop Using Images to Display Text
6. Optimize Image Sizes by Using the Correct File Format
7. Optimize the Way You Write Code
8. Load JavaScript at the End of Your Document
9. Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
10. Optimize Web Caching

Comment: Funny how the article misses the obvious optimisation - turn on gzip (oh and keep-alive)